# Почему деталь затвора называется "золотник"?

Tags: этимология

В клапанах есть делать затворного механизма, которая называется золотник. Заинтересовало название. Почему он так называется? Вряд ли его когда-либо делали из золота.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь, что именно от золота. 
Навскидку - происходит от русской меры веса *золотник* (1/96 фунта - чуть меньше пяти грамм), название которой, в свою очередь, по наиболее популярной версии восходит к золотой монете "золотник".

Не совсем, правда, понятно как было перенесено название меры на устройство, но эта версия совсем не выглядит неправдоподобной для тех, кто знаком с устройством самого золотника. Он предназначен для отмеривания строго определенной порции рабочей смеси (жидкости или газа) с большой точностью.